# Working on django projects, where I have multiple projects and multiple databases, I want to access all databases in everyapp

Tags: django, multiple-databases

I have 3 projects (A, B, C) and 3 databases (DB1, DB2, DB3). I have defined Model `common` in project A and want to access same model in Project B. I want to access every database with each application. I don't know how to configure settings files so i can use every database. I tried [django's multi-db](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/multi-db/) but didn't get what I need.

Project A has Model `UserAttributes()`, how can I use this model in Project B or project C as a shared database?

Comment: It sounds like it should be one single project rather than 3 separate ones?

Answer (score 0):

Have you think about interacting between applications using an API? Give a try to django-rest-framework. You can have an API view in application A that receives GET and POST requests to query and alter the `common` model.